# determining the data type of an image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am reading the image in Ipl format and then convert it into Mat form. then I try to dispaly the number of rows,columns,channels and depth of the image. the result of the first three is as expected however the result of the depth is:

Code line:
    cout<<"   "<<"Depth   ="<

Result:
    Depth = 0

could anyone tell me what does this mean???

Comment: Doesn't Depth return the enum relating to the depth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[depth](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth) is a flag (#defined int in `types_c.h`), to print it use for example:

```
const char* depthToStr(int depth) {
  switch(depth){
    case CV_8U: return "unsigned char";
    case CV_8S: return "char";
    case CV_16U: return "unsigned short";
    case CV_16S: return "short";
    case CV_32S: return "int";
    case CV_32F: return "float";
    case CV_64F: return "double";
  }
  return "invalid type!";
}
```

and use like this: `cout << "depth = " << depthToStr(mat.depth()) << endl;`

Comment: Thanks it worked:) have you defined this function yourself?@Antoine

Comment: Yes, I'm not aware of an equivalent function in the openCV API.

Comment: @AaymanKhalid: You can also use this switch/case when you implement a processing algorithm which behaves differently if the image is float or discrete for instance. Just replace `return "type name"` with `function_specialized_for_type(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth) can tell you what it means:

> The method returns the identifier of the matrix element depth (the
>   type of each individual channel). For example, for a 16-bit signed
>   3-channel array, the method returns CV_16S.

You should check it out, it's quite useful.